# Shared Libraries in Developer M Preview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to test out my application on the Android M dev preview.

My application is using a Shared library, which I have placed in jni/libs/armeabi inside of Android Studio. I believe when it calls `System.loadLibrary("myLib")` it is throwing the following UnsatisfiedLinkError.  Is anyone else having this issue?  Android 5.x has no problem with this.

```
06-02 08:24:28.004  16505-16505/com.me.workflow E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.me.workflow, PID: 16505
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "{Path}/Android/Workflow/mobile/src/main//obj/local/armeabi/myLib.so" not found
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:368)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
            at com.me.workflow.service.WorkflowService.<clinit>(WorkflowService.java:108)
            at com.me.workflow.activities.BaseServiceActivity.startWorkflowService(BaseServiceActivity.java:501)
            at com.me.workflow.activities.WelcomeActivity.deployAndroidSetup(WelcomeActivity.java:639)
            at com.me.workflow.activities.WelcomeActivity.onFileOperationCompleted(WelcomeActivity.java:842)
            at com.me.workflow.tasks.CopyFromAssets.onPostExecute(CopyFromAssets.java:76)
            at com.me.workflow.tasks.CopyFromAssets.onPostExecute(CopyFromAssets.java:42)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:649)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:666)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5401)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:725)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:615)
```

Update:

I have received some feedback on the issue. In my Android.mk file I have the line below, currently the belief is that this path is not correct and that it is not finding the file because of it.

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES    := libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/myLib.so
```

https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2239

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem, by making sure my prebuild of the library had a soname set.  See the following Android Developer Preview issue thread

https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2239

item number 10 in the thread talks about my prebuilt needing to have the soname set, which I previously had not.

so in my library build script I added -Wl,-soname,lib{mylibname}.so to my LDFLAGS variable

```
export LDFLAGS="--sysroot ${TOOL_PREFIX}/sysroot -L${PREFIX}/lib -L${TOOL_PREFIX}/lib ${LDFLAGS_EXTRA} -Wl,-soname,libmylib1.0.so"
```

Comment: Good day. Have the same issue, have got an advice from google's support to set soname attribute manually for prebuild library which i use. I'm setting this flag in Android.mk of prebuild library with command LOCAL_LDFLAGS    := -Wl,-soname,lib{mylib}.so, rebuild project witn ndk-build command but newly generated mylib.so still hasn't soname attribute. What is the correct way to set this flag to make it have effect, where and how should it be set? Thank you. Issue thread is https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175589