# How to link with relative NEEDED path with Android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I have library that should be linked against another library (.so).
It is build correctly but in `NEEDED` fields i can see absolute library path and Android Marshmallow throws `UnsatisfiedLinkError`:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/foo_jni/app/obj/local/armeabi/libfoo.so" not found

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := foo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libfoo.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := /Volumes/Transcend/dev/src/libfoo-ios/lib/libfoo/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := foo_wrapper
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := foo_wrapper.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := foo
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := /Volumes/Transcend/dev/src/libfoo/lib/libfoo/include
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog

# ARM (coffeecatch)
#LOCAL_CFLAGS := -funwind-tables -Wl,--no-merge-exidx-entries

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Here is read-elf result:

```
MBA-Anton:jni asmirnov$ /softdev/arm-toolchain-gcc4.8/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-readelf -d ../libs/armeabi/libfoo_wrapper.so | grep NEEDED
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [/Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/foo_jni/app/obj/local/armeabi/libfoo.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [liblog.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libstdc++.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libm.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libdl.so]
```

How can i link to use relative path for `libfoo` just like for `libm`?

Comment: seems to be similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30596250/shared-libraries-in-developer-m-preview